# Add Nested Headers over a group of Headers in DetailsList in FluentUI

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fluent-ui, fluentui-react

I am trying to add custom headers to group Headers of a Detail List in Fluent UI but not able to do. I think we can do this using onRenderDetailsListHeader but I got no clue about the implementation.

[image]